# Creating a backing store and cache strategy using MonoTouch

Tags: caching, serialization, xamarin.ios

While I have seen an example of using CoreData to perform this (and the subsequent mess that it leaves in your code), I would prefer to create a simple backing store to sqllite. Are there any simple examples or decent cache strategy mechanisms that are simple to call, or is it realy as simple as writing .Searalize() and sticking the values in a table for retrieval upon startup?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest taking a look at [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/Projects/CoolStorage/Home), a cross platform sqlite-compatible ORM that supports MonoTouch. In my opinion it's pretty intuitive and could possibly be a good fit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at MonoTouch.Dialog.UrlImageStore?
https://github.com/Redth/MonoTouch.UrlImageStore

What is it?
A utility library for Lazy Loading and Caching images from urls for your application.

Go there and see the examples.